# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-7

Please I can't find where is the problem!
it say like :

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   POST.

but I don't know how to solve this problem.

**This is the Controller.**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Imports\ProductsImport;
    use Excel;

    class ProductController extends Controller
    {
        public function storeData(Request $request)
        {
            //VALIDASI
            $this->validate($request, [
                'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
            ]);

            if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
                $file = $request->file('file'); //GET FILE
                Excel::import(new ProductsImport, $file); //IMPORT FILE
                return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Upload success']);
            }
            return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Please choose file before']);
        }
    }
```

**This is the Route.**

```
Route::post('/', 'ProductController@storeData');
```

**This is The View.**

```
<form action="{{ route('/') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @if (session('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('success') }}
   </div>
   @endif
   @if (session('error'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('error') }}
   </div>
   @endif
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">File (.xls, .xlsx)</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file">
      <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('file') }}</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Upload</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: provide the full balde file

Comment: because of your code is so wrong this method come when you hit get method instead of post method i know what is your problem

Comment: on the form I make method = post and I also make route with post, so why does laravel display the GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Your route needs to support both GET and POST methods.